# how to fetch int value from database and display string value instead of that int value in table using php and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display the string values in HTML table based on the int value fetched from mySQL database.
it is a checking process of users prime member or not.

My HTML Code is

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Store Name</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">  Prime </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>

            <?php 
                while($eachitem = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
            ?>
  
           <tr>
               <td> <?php echo remove_junk($eachitem['name']); ?></td>
               <td class="text-center"> <?php echo        remove_junk($eachitem['prime']); ?></td>
                    
              </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody> 
      </table>
```

And I have my db configuration in config.php

```
  <?php
     include('config.php');
  
    // SQL query to select data from database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM store ";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
  ?>
```

The HTML code for adding prime to database is

```
 <select name="prime" class="form-control">
   <option value="0">Not prime</option>
   <option value="1">prime</option>
 </select>
```

I have Int values 0 and 1 in store table row names prime.
Now i need to show No instead on 0 and Yes instead of 1 without changing drop down values in HTML

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I think just this will do it? `echo remove_junk($eachitem['prime']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';`, although it also depends on what `remove_junk` does

Comment: Also, unless you only posted a subset of a code, there isn't a good reason to have the two loops, you can consolidate down to just the `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the ternary operator `?` (a.k.a. conditional operator). It has the form

```
(condition) ? (what to do if condition is true) : (what to do if condition is false);
```

For your code, change

```
<?php echo remove_junk($eachitem['prime']); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo remove_junk($eachitem['prime']) ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?>
```